# How to perform some action when device is connected to WiFi and app is terminated?

Tags: ios, swift

How should I communicate with server or do some action when my device is connected to the WiFi and my app is terminated (not runnning on background/foreground)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for UIApplicationDelegate's [`applicationWillTerminate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) API (which has a companion `UIApplicationWillTerminate` notification you can observer), you have approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return before the app dies.

If this were my problem, I'd be wondering if five seconds is that long enough to reliably talk to the server or do any useful action aside from cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

If your app goes in **Terminated** state, you can't perform any operation. The thing you could've done is in the **Background** state. You should go through this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) for better understanding on **iOS App Lifecycle**.

Comment: Then how should i update the WiFi name when it connected to WiFi or chnage from one WiFi to another when  my app is terminated. 
for example my app is terminated and and i am connected to WiFi now i want to update to server side about the WiFi detail then how can i do that is there any way or its not possible

Comment: @YuvrajKale Why do you need to send updates to the server when the app is **Terminated**? Can't you do that when your app is in the **Background** state?

Comment: Actully my app is based on WiFi connection so if device is connected to new WiFi or connected to WiFi when app is terminated(no running on background/forground) that time i want to update the WiFi detail to the server. That is why i want to update to the servert when app is terminated